# How to update a multiple objects in an array with jq

Tags: arrays, json, edit, jq

Using jq I would like to conditionally update the objects in the `"folders"` array. 
For each object which contains `"cand_name":"folderA"` a new attribute `"files"` which has the value of `compare.files` should be added

```
{
  "tmp":{
    "folders":[
      {
        "ref_name":"folderB",
        "cand_name":"folderA"
      },
      {
        "ref_name":"folderC",
        "cand_name":"folderA"
      },
      {
        "ref_name":"folderC",
        "cand_name":"folderE"
      }
    ],
    "compare":{
      "files":[
        {
          "candidate":"Z3S1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For the above input the expected output should be

```
{
  "tmp":{
    "folders":[
      {
        "ref_name":"folderB",
        "cand_name":"folderA"
        "files":[
          {
            "candidate":"Z3S1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ref_name":"folderC",
        "cand_name":"folderA"
        "files":[
          {
            "candidate":"Z3S1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ref_name":"folderC",
        "cand_name":"folderE"
      }
    ],
    "compare":{
      "files":[
        {
          "candidate":"Z3S1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: There is a mismatch between the problem description and the expected output. Please adjust one or the other.

Comment: Sorry changed "cand_name":"folderE" to "cand_name":"folderA" so that the description now matches the expected result

Answer (score 0):

The key to a simple solution is `|=`. Using the expected output as a guide to the intended requirements, one could write:

```
.tmp.compare.files as $f
| .tmp.folders 
  |= map( if .cand_name=="folderA" 
          then .files = $f else . end)
```

Comment: I was off on a totally wrong path with my attempts - your solution works great, many thanks.